# Angled background for div

Tags: html, css

Please see the following image & if anyone can help me in this one

[image]
[image]

See above images first one is what its currently looking & I want it to look exactly like second image

I want to make a curve between these two backgrounds as you see in Image 2. 
I have two different div with different background.

I have tried the to do the border radius but I doesn't gave me desired results

Comment: can you show us the code of first one?

Comment: Share the code to recreate your problem please.

Comment: Check this out: **http://codepen.io/pipozoft/pen/vBwjl**